# Hazelcast 3.4 'max-size' attribute of hazelcast IMap is not working correctly

Tags: spring, hazelcast, max-size

I am using `hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd`. My **hazelcast** map configuration is given below.

```
<hz:map name="defaultMap"
                    backup-count="1"
                    max-size="5000"
                    max-size-policy = "PER_NODE"
                    eviction-percentage="50"
                    read-backup-data="true"    
                    eviction-policy="LRU"
                    merge-policy=
                        "com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy"
                    time-to-live-seconds="0"
                >
```

I have given `max-size = 5000`. I have **12000 records** and **defaultMap** is loading **12000 records** in it if i do insert into it. I am confused here ,how it can load more data than its actual size **5000**. I am getting no exception in inserting 12000 data records.

And one more thing its eviction configuration is not working also. I want to evict my cache by 50 percent if it reaches its max-size limit.

Can any body help me? Its very urgent.What i am missing ?

Comment: Please check the ttl, you have set ttl to 0 means infinte time means no policy for expiration and also check max-idle-seconds attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `max-size-policy = "PER_NODE"` setting which means maximum number of map entries in **each Hazelcast instance**, not the whole Hazelcast cluster (or the whole map).

In Hazelcast 2.x releases, the default value for max-size eviction policy was `cluster_wide_map_size`. In 3.x releases, it is replaced with `PER_NODE`.

There are other settings as well. For detailed map eviction settings and examples, you can check [this](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/preface.html) out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have gone through documentation. I am using eviction-policy="LRU" which means Least Recently Used entries will be evicted from cache after 'max-size' limit is reached. But my newly added entries are getting evicted instead of old entries.What would be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

LFU: Least Frequently Used
LRU:Least Recently Used
NONE:None
RANDOM:Randomly
I think You would have used LRU instead of LFU..

Answer (score -3):

You can use this property to resolve your issue:

```
eviction-policy="LFU"
```

Comment: OP stated, "But my newly added entries are getting evicted instead of old entries.What would be the issue?" Why would you suggest a policy that  evicts least frequently used entries as a solution?